# OrientDB: MaxDirectMemorySize vs Dstorage.diskCache.bufferSize

Tags: jvm, orientdb

It is not clear what the difference is between MaxDirectMemorySize and Dstorage.diskCache.bufferSize.  They both seem to be off heap. Are they redundant when both are specified?

> Docs :  The size of direct memory consumed by OrientDB is limited by
>   the size of the disk cache (variable storage.diskCache.bufferSize).  https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Embedded-Server.html

The docs seem to imply that they refer to the same space, but that the driectmemorysize is limited by the buffer size.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MaxDirectMemorySize` is a JVM setting that limits all direct byte buffer allocations within that JVM instance.

`storage.diskCache.bufferSize` is an application setting that limits direct byte buffer allocations for the purpose of IO caching in orientdb.

Comment: If we set MaxDirectMemorySize, does it automatically set a reasonable value for storage.diskCache.bufferSize and/or similar application settings.

Comment: the documentation you have linked to yourself mentions the default it uses

Comment: My eyes must not be able to focus tonight.  I don't see on that page where it gives a default for storage.diskCache.bufferSize in relation to MaxDirectMemorySize.  I do see a defualt given for MaxDirectMemorySize.